# Flutter : Write and Read Text File into External Storage

Tags: flutter, text-files, android-external-storage, read-write

I want to save few user information in different line inside external storage. This is because when user come in for the second time they don't have to login again the system will check either the file is exist, if yes then read the text file and proceed to the dashboard page.

I tried this code but it seem like its not working. All the details are getting from the API. I'm expecting after calling to the API, this details will be kept inside the external storage.

```dart
await StorageHelper.writeTextToFile(
            "custInfo.txt",
                '\n${ApiSetting.CompanyID}'
                '\n${ApiSetting.apiURL}'
                '\n${ApiSetting.CompanyName}');
```

**Storage Helper class**

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class StorageHelper{


  static Future<String> get _localPath async{
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    return directory.path;
  }

  static Future<File> _getLocalFile(String fileName) async{
    final localPath = await _localPath;
    return File("$localPath/$fileName");
  }

  static Future<File> writeTextToFile(String fileName, String text) async{
    final file = await _getLocalFile(fileName);
    return file.writeAsString(text);
  }

  static Future<String> readFromFile(String fileName) async{
    try{

    }catch(e){
      return ""; 
    }
    final file = await _getLocalFile(fileName);
    return file.readAsString();
  }

  static Future<File> writeBytesToFile(String fileName, Uint8List data) async{
    final file = await _getLocalFile(fileName);
    return file.writeAsBytes(data);
  }
}
```